# Using custom property in WHERE IN clause with $X{} in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I currently have a parameter called `countries` of type `java.util.List` and I'm using it in a `WHERE IN` clause as follows:

```
AND $X{IN, rd.country_id, countries}
```

In my app I must convert my `List<Country>` to `List<Integer>` so that I can use it to make the IN clause, otherwise Jasper would create something like `country_id IN ("Argentina", "Brazil")` instead of using the IDs.

I was wondering if its possible to use `List<Country>` as my parameter and telling `$X{}` to use the field **id** to create the IN clause so that I can use the `toString()` method to show what countries the user has selected, any idea? thanks

Comment: nope @willome, I'd get ´MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '$X.id' in 'where clause'´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method i can think of right now  is to have a java class which will take your List of type countryname and return List of type countryId .
you have to make another parameter of type List.This parameter will call the java method.and then you can use this parameter in you query

I assume that the answer provided by @Lisa is not working in this case.

Edit:
Place the java class in your project classpath 
The "<>" tags were not visible

Comment: that's exactly what I'm doing right now in my controller logic, but I'd like to apply it in the report.. so where should I declare that class so I can make use of it while writing the report query?

Comment: @cjava one example would be great

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're deploying this report, but could you set the input control's visible column to the country name, but set the value column to the country ID?

If you're unable to edit the input control, what about modifying your query to handle the country name to ID conversion?

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE countryID IN (SELECT countryID
                    FROM countryTable
                    WHERE $X{IN, countryName, countries}
                    )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @Lisa but this is a summary report so I only want to show wich countries has been chosen in the report header